# Should data in in json file 'structured using li tags?

Tags: html, reactjs, json, django, bulletedlist

```
[
  {
    "model": "db.service",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "catagory_name": "New host",
      "service_name": "<ul><li>Trip planning</li><li>Host shop</li></ul>"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "db.service",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "catagory_name": "TOURING HOSTS",
      "service_name": "Tour of location"
    }
```

and it has another 5 written like the second activity. This is shown on the front end as a drop down of the activities (service_name). However the tech lead wants me to show trip planning as a bulleted activity, like this

- Trip Planning
- Host Shop

All as one selection.

In the front end code, the previous intern has used regex to seek the li and ul tags and replace them with || for some reason. He wants me to get rod of those which is easy enough, but I was wondering if I should keep the code to seek the tags and somehow make them into bullet points.

I have tried replacing the || with & but get &&, I then try replacing && with & but that doesn't work and there are still || in the code, so I tried replaceAll. However this still doesn't get me bullet points. Front end is react. I tried putting the code in brackets with li tags and that didn't work neither.

code listing the activities in the drop down

```
 {pricing &&
                  targetValue &&
                  pricing.map((service, index) => {
                    if (targetValue === service.service_info.service_name) {
                      return service.service_info.service_name.includes(
                        "<li>"
                      ) ? (
                        <Grid item className={classes.headlineText}>
                          
                          {handleServiceName(service.service_info.service_name)}
                        </Grid>
                      ) : (
                        <Grid item className={classes.headlineText}>
                          {service.service_info.service_name}
                        </Grid>
                      );
                    }
                  })}
              </Grid>
```

Code handling regex

````
    const regex = /<[^>]+>/g;
    const split_string = string;
    const new_str = string.replace(regex, " | ");
    return new_str;
  };```
````

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: Ive added more code in the post